# Update variable for each row in a SELECT in Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, foreach

I am normally working with MS SQL. I have a piece of code which I might have to translate to Oracle SQL. In this piece of code I update two variables for each row in order to find the max value of concurrent users.

My question is if it is possible to do the same as what is being done in the MS SQL code below in Oracle?

```
-- The creation of this test table is not relevant to my question.
-- It is just there to make a working example
SELECT {ts '2012-09-03 10:12:00'} AS eventTime, 1 AS change
INTO #EVENTS
UNION ALL SELECT {ts '2012-09-03 10:24:00'}, 1
UNION ALL SELECT {ts '2012-09-03 10:25:00'}, 1
UNION ALL SELECT {ts '2012-09-03 11:02:00'}, -1
UNION ALL SELECT {ts '2012-09-03 11:25:00'}, 1
UNION ALL SELECT {ts '2012-09-03 11:34:00'}, 1
UNION ALL SELECT {ts '2012-09-03 12:15:00'}, -1
UNION ALL SELECT {ts '2012-09-03 13:50:00'}, -1
UNION ALL SELECT {ts '2012-09-03 14:20:00'}, -1
UNION ALL SELECT {ts '2012-09-03 14:44:00'}, -1

DECLARE @count int, @maxUsers int
SET @count = 0
SET @maxUsers = 0

-- This part is what is in question. Can you do something similar in Oracle?
-- Having calculation done for each row and store it in a variable for
-- the next row.
SELECT
    @count = @count + change,
    @maxUsers = CASE WHEN @count > @maxUsers THEN @count ELSE @maxUsers END
FROM #EVENTS
ORDER BY eventTime ASC

PRINT @maxUsers -- Prints the value 4

DROP TABLE #EVENTS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has analytic functions that can be used to get things like running totals.

```
SELECT MAX(CURRENTUSERS) FROM
(
  SELECT SUM(CHANGE) OVER (ORDER BY eventTime) AS CURRENTUSERS 
  FROM EVENTS
)
```

Comment: While MSSQL also has OVER, I can't return a list of running totals which is indeed what I need. It seems to be a good way (or actually better way) to solve the same problem. Using local variables is the fastest solution on MSSQL. Thanks for your Oracle insights!

Comment: I believe it is now supported in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could. Replace #EVENTS using WITH clause, get rid of DROP and put it into single SQL statement using select into clause. In  order to do PRINT use dbms_output.put_line. I presume ORDER BY will not work so you have to play with ROWNUMBER

Comment: In my real code I already use WITH. I saw it existed in Oracle too. Nice :) . But, it is quite important that the summary events happens in chronological order. I don't see how to do this with ROWNUMBER (if it works similar to MSSQL's ROW_NUMBER) without falling back to using a CURSOR (or whatever it is called in Oracle). Doing that calculation in the correct order for each row is the core of the question.